# retain state in navigation drawer fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

i have a navigation drawer project which I just modify from the "Create New Project > Navigation Drawer" using Android Studio. There are several 'menus' in the navigation drawer, on each opens up different fragments.. the problem is every time when I navigate using the drawer, the fragments are re-created. Means that when the user have done some changes on a fragment, later when the user re-visits the fragment again, the changes are lost. I've used setRetainInstance(true); but that only works for orientation change it seems.

here's a part of my code on which I use to display the selected fragments:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }

        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragmentDashboard");
                if (fragment == null){
                    fragment = new Dashboard();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentDashboard");
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }else{
                    transaction.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentDashboard"));
                    transaction.commit();
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragmentExpenses");
                if (fragment == null) {
                    fragment = new Expenses();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentExpenses");
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }else{
                    transaction.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentExpenses"));
                    transaction.commit();
                    fm.popBackStack();
                }

                break;


            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

edit: this question [Save fragment state with navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448946/save-fragment-state-with-navigation-drawer) is the close solution I get to my problem, but the answer is too brief.. and I'm pretty new in android development. so can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

### **Try this Code** :: Instead of `replacing-fragments` .... EveryTime `Hide` and `Show` the fragments

***Description***::

- Instead of `destroying the fragments` .... create the `fragment` for
  the first time and every other time `find the fragment and use it`,
  `instead of replacing it`

---

***Instead of code*** ::

```
   private void selectItem(int position) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
            if (mDrawerListView != null) {
                mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
            if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
            }
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
            }

            Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragmentDashboard");
                    if (fragment == null){
                        fragment = new Dashboard();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentDashboard");
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }else{
                        transaction.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentDashboard"));
                        transaction.commit();
                        fm.popBackStack();
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragmentExpenses");
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new Expenses();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentExpenses");
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }else{
                        transaction.remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentExpenses"));
                        transaction.commit();
                        fm.popBackStack();
                    }

                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

---

***Use this::***

```
   private void selectItem(int position) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
            if (mDrawerListView != null) {
                mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
            if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
            }
            if (mCallbacks != null) {
                mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
            }

            Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragmentDashboard");
                    if (fragment == null){
                        fragment = new Dashboard();
                        transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentDashboard");
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }else{
                        transaction.show(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentDashboard"));
                        transaction.commit();
                        fm.popBackStack();
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragmentExpenses");
                    if (fragment == null) {
                        fragment = new Expenses();
                        transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, "fragmentExpenses");
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                    }else{
                        transaction.show(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentExpenses"));
                        transaction.commit();
                        fm.popBackStack();
                    }

                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

***[Check Developers site for more info](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace)***

Comment: from what I see, just replace the code 'transaction.replace' to 'transaction.add' in 'if' and replace the code 'transaction.remove' to 'transaction.show' in 'else' right? if it yes, I've tried it and it doesn't work. Furthermore the UI of the fragments become crazy, in terms of the objects that I created in the 1st fragment would appear in the 2nd fragment.

Comment: @imin ..... Hmmm .... If say in fragment one you enter some data you go to fragment2 and come back again you can use bundle to pass between activities(Just a guess, ive not tested it) .... Give it a try with your initial configuration using replace..... You can use application variable ...but i dont recomend it because of heavy lifting of data ... so try passing bundle between fragments and use flags to check and set the data in fragments !