# How to save state with navigation drawer and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-savedstate

I have an application with a navigation drawer, one activity and many fragments. When I change the device orientation my main activity is recreate and it's my main fragment who appears, not the current fragment. Just like when I launch the app.

How can I restore the current fragment and maybe the data associated with the selected fragment ?

I Have seen this post but it doesn't work : [Save fragment state with navigation drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448946/save-fragment-state-with-navigation-drawer)

Thanks in advance to those who can help me.

Comment: did you tried adding configchanges to the manifest

Comment: I thought of something that can be considered a hack; whenever you enter a new fragment, save its' position into the SharedPreferences and then onConfigurationChange read the position from SharedPrefs and instantiate the right fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the fragment states are already persisted for you.

This is what I do:  I check if `savedInstanceState` is null.  If it is, I execute the `FragmentManager` transaction to display the main fragment.  If it is not null, it means the fragment state is persisted.  I don't do any kind of transaction, and the fragment is recreated for me from the persisted state.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in my onCreate I executed the `FragmentManager` to display one or another Fragment according to `SharedPreferences`. So I just added the condition on `savedInstanceState == null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (savedInstanceState == null){
    //Launch HomeFragment onStart...
    Fragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
}
```

I added this to `onCreate` in my Main Activity